# Creating an Image/Grid solution with CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I'm building a new website and looking for a solution for this problem (PHP, MySQL, using Zurb Foundation).

I want to create an image I can zoom in and out from, that'll be made of 1,000,000 pieces.
Each piece should be clickable and upon click more information should arrive from the backend.
The color of each piece depends on info coming from the DB as well. The pieces are like pixels.

So - three dilemmas:

1. How do I structure the data?
2. How do I create an image with clickable pieces without images?
3. How can I shape the page so it won't load slowly?

Thanks!
Dana

Comment: about `3` - try to use in sprite if your images are prepared in advance http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: You'd probably want to use something like AJAX to access the data - if you have a million pieces of it you don't really want it all to be on the page at once.

Is each piece going to be square shaped? And are they going to be pixel-like (i.e. each square a solid colour - then combining to form the larger image?). If so, you could build a large grid with a table structure and just set the background of each cell - the main problem there is figuring out a way to convert an image into a series of coloured cells (without doing it manually - which would take years).

Comment: @Kez A table was my initial thought, but I don't want to do this to myself..

Comment: Honestly, trying to load a table with a million cells would probably cause a lot of trouble.

I think if you were to do this, it would likely need to be with SVG, especially as you want to zoom in and out. I suspect you may need to look into a more powerful language to achieve it though.

Answer (score 0):

So you probably want to use a table to store all your images:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>   <a> Each small image </a>   </td>
    <td>   <a> Each small image </a>   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>   <a> Each small image </a>   </td>
    <td>   <a> Each small image </a>   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Though if you do this you should have small images to improve load time. This should stop the page loading slowly.

Edit: If you are trying to do something like this:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/NineImages/
but on a bigger scale than try making a javascript function that makes the image bigger and sets the image's src to a variable gotten from a mySql DB.

Gab

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do?